# What glib do I need?

Tags: compiling, glib

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and I am trying to compile the [cpabe toolkit](http://acsc.cs.utexas.edu/cpabe/), but first I have to compile libbswabe. However, when I try to build libbswabe-0.9 it gives me an error stating that glib.h cannot be found. Here is the relevant text from the config.log file:

```
configure:4013: checking for GLIB - version >= 2.0.0
configure:4145: result: no
configure:4173: gcc -o conftest -O3 -Wall   -O3 -Wall conftest.c -lcrypto   >&5
conftest.c:31:18: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

What is glib.h and how do I install it? And I did successfully enter `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev` into the command line.

Comment: If you enter `dpkg -S glib.h`, it should return `libglib2.0-dev: /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h` if you have `libglib2.0-dev` installed.

Comment: It did just that, but it still is not found when I try to compile libbswabe.